# FullCalendar event duplicate after the first even

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

when I select an event it's ok, after I get duplicated, quadrupled, etc.
Why? I don't undertastand why it's

This is my code in javascript

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        snapDuration: '00:30:00',
        selectable: true,
        aspectRatio: 1.8,
        scrollTime: '08:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
        resources: '{!! route('fullcalendar.roomall') !!}',
        events: '{!! route('fullcalendar.bookingall') !!}',
        select: function( start, end, jsEvent, view, resourceId) {

            $('#event-modal').find('input[name=title]').val('');
            // set values in inputs
            $('#event-modal').find('input[name=evtStart]').val(
                    start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
            );
            $('#event-modal').find('input[name=evtEnd]').val(
                    end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
            );
            // show modal dialog
            $('#event-modal').modal('show');
            /*
             bind event submit. Will perform a ajax call in order to save the event to the database.
             When save is successful, close modal dialog and refresh fullcalendar.
             */

            $("#event-modal").on('click','.save', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var id = resourceId['id'];
                var roomName = resourceId['title'];
                var title = $('#title').val();
                var start = $('#evtStart').val();
                var end = $('#evtEnd').val();
                $('#event-modal').modal('hide');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ route('events.save') }}',
                    data: $("#event-modal").serialize(),
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                        'title': title,
                        'start': start,
                        'end': end,
                        'roomId': id,
                        'roomName': roomName
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        callback(response);
                        $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents');

                    }
                });
            });
        },
});
```

when I select an event it's ok, after I get duplicated, quadrupled, etc.
Why? I don't undertastand why it's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you keep on adding more and more "click" event handlers to the "save" button every time the "select" callback runs.

```
$("#event-modal").off("click", ".save").on('click','.save', function(event) {
```

should fix your issue ([.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) removes the specified event handlers from the element).

Questions of this nature get asked all the time. You need to understand that adding an event handler to an element doesn't remove the previous ones, they can all exist together, and they all will continue to respond to events until you remove them.

Comment: ADyson you are a master, thanks!!! I resolved and and I will remember your suggestion

Comment: But I noticed that in this way the "" CLOSE "button of the modal does not work anymore. Why? ok, i resolved add a class to the close button $("#event-modal").off('click','.btn-default').on('click','.save', function(event)

Comment: because we removed all "click" events for anything inside or underneath the "event-modal" element. Sorry about that. See amended answer above. Added a link to the documentation too so you can see why I changed it like that.

Comment: You need to add it to the question, not in a separate answer - it's not an answer to the question! But...does my change above not solve the issue already? I'm not sure why you've added that code?